# How to write a compareTo() method for Text version of arrywritable

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a mapreduce code and my intermediate mapper output key is a Text version of ArrayWritable and i have created a class TextArrayWritable and extended ArrayWritable.Below is my code

public class TextArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable 
{

```
//private Writable[] values;
public TextArrayWritable()
{
    super(Text.class);

}
public TextArrayWritable(String[] strings)
{
    super(Text.class);
    Text[] texts=new Text[strings.length];
    for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++)
    {
        texts[i]=new Text(strings[i]);
    }
    set(texts);
}
public String[] returnarray(Text[] mytext)
{
    //super(Text.class);
    String[] mystr=new String[mytext.length];
    //ArrayList<String> mylist=new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<mystr.length;i++)
    {
        mystr[i]=mystr[i].toString();
    }
    return mystr;
}
 public Text[] toArray() {
     return (Text[]) super.toArray();
     }
```

}

How to write a compareTo() method for the above class i understand it needs to implemented by implementing WritableComparable interface but not sure how  to write a method.

Edit:
It fails with below error:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class TextArrayWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class TextArrayWritable
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getOutputKeyComparator(JobConf.java:795)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:964)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:673)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the [`ArrayWritable` documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html) correctly, to create a `TextArrayWritable` all you need is this:

```
public class TextArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
    public TextArrayWritable() { super(Text.class); }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer, when i run the job it fails with the mentioned error. As per my understanding it is  not able to cast the compareTo() method for textarraywritable of the default WritableComparable interface and asking me to override the compareTo() method for this textarraywritable.

Comment: Ya even it fails with the same error. I have also implanted the same piece of code in my original code.